# Ссылки на сторонние сайты

Tags: вирусы

Всем привет. Есть сайт, который сделал недавно. Адрес - resnitsy.kands.spb.ru

Проблема в том, что в `<head>` сайта добавляются непонятные ссылки (pliaff-up):

[image: Непонятные ссылки]

Кто знает, почему это может происходить? Что это за скрипты? При переходе на сервер этих скриптов выдает 403, в изначальном DOM этих ссылок нет

Comment: ну например это может быть бесплатный хост и вставляет что-то своё. а может ты пользуешься расширениями браузеров, которые что-то вставляют в страницы. да и в целом почисти свои браузеры..

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хост reg.ru) Насчет расширений - сейчас посмотрим на других браузерах

Comment: @АлексейШиманский собстна, да, расширение браузера))

Comment: Крч, надо комп на малварей почистить в целом

Comment: **И после этого поменять все пароли на почтах, сайтах и т.д. и т.п.!**

Comment: @Visman и сообщить их нам, для сохранности)

Comment: Похоже, таки проблема не в сайте :-)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй удалить все используемые расширения в браузере.
[Как удалить расширение в Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/2589434?hl=ru)
[Как удалить расширение в Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/ru/kb/udalenie-dopolnenij)
[Как удалить расширение в Opera](http://help.opera.com/Windows/11.50/ru/extensions.html)